# Server is unreachable after domain registrar change even after updating DNS records

Tags: node.js, dns, centos7

I recently changed domain registrars for my domain and the transfer was complete.

I added all the DNS records from my old registrar to the new one and changed nameservers to the new one. Its been over 72 hours since these changes have been made.

The A record is for a subdomain which we entered into the Name field and the IP in the Value field. Which is identical to the entry on the other registrar.

e.g. A trader 55.55.55.55

There was no change to the server itself which is running a nodejs app, listening on port 3000.

When I try to connect to the URL now in the browser, it gives a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.

There were no changes to firewall/iptables config on the server, we simply just switched domain registrars and pointed the domain on the new registrar to the IP address.

I've tried disabling the firewalld service on the server to see if it could go through and it didn't as well.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check to see what the WHOIS of the domain actually reports it has as the Name Servers you can use the ICANN tool for this which is here:
https://lookup.icann.org/en/lookup

If this shows the correctly updated Name Servers I would try using an external DNS checking tool like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ where I would first check that the Name Servers have been updated correctly and then start looking at the different A records that you moved over.

Comment: The nameservers look correct from ICANN and the correct IP is populating in whatsmydns.net. I have a feeling its the server, but I didn't make any changes to server so I want to rule it out. Somehow I feel like its the server even though no changes were made to it. I've checked both ipchicken.com and whatsmyip.com to see if the IP changed but it hasn't. I lost as to what else it could be.

Comment: I'm not too sure as the error message you gave shows that its at the DNS level. I guess it could be local caching try an online browser such as https://www.browserling.com/ if this loads your site then clear all your local browsing cache, close your browsers and try again. You could also try going directly to the IP address of your server, that should load something even if its the default landing page.